# How can I get the VM method signature of a method in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

For adding instrumentation roots to a Profiler, I need to write the method signature.
For example, in case of the method:

```
String toString()
```

The VM Method signature is

```
()Ljava/lang/String;
```

Question is, is there any way to check such signatures in Eclipse if you have the source code?  Is there any shortcut to see this?

I want to check this manually

Comment: Do you need an API call or do you want to check manually?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you open the compiled class file without linking the source (easiest way is simply to do File -> Open File and look for the compiled class file), then Eclipse shows you a decompiled version of the Java file. You can see for example:

```
// Method descriptor #15 ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
// Stack: 4, Locals: 4
public static void main(java.lang.String[] args);
```

The first Method descriptor shows the signature.